# How do I fix highchart to display series correctly with a special marker

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use a special marker to display in Highcharts on a specific point. I changed data as per highchart spec, somehow it is not working and not able to read those specific points to display as series.

Please check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sridharspeaks/pen/BaLgpJe).

The actual code is here:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    "time": {
        "useUTC": false
    },
    "toolbar": false,
    "title": {
        "align": "left",
        "verticalAlign": "top",
        "x": 8,
        "y": 0,
        "style": {
            "fontFamily": "Roboto, sans-serif",
            "color": "#203459",
            "fontWeight": 500,
            "fontSize": "14px"
        },
        "text": "Sample Graph"
    },
    "chart": {
        zoomType: 'x',
        panning: true,
        panKey: 'shift',

    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": null
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "alignTicks": false,
        "crosshair": true,
        "type": "datetime"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "align": 'left'
        },
    },
    "credits": null,
    "legend": false,
    "tooltip": {
        "crosshairs": true,
        "shared": true,
        "split": false,
        "pointFormat": "{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>",
        "xDateFormat": "%A, %b %e, %Y %H:%M"
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "series": {
            "label": {
                "connectorAllowed": false
            }
        },
        "area": {
            "dataLabels": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "fillColor": {
                "linearGradient": {
                    "x1": 0,
                    "y1": 0,
                    "x2": 0,
                    "y2": 1
                },
                "stops": [
                    [
                        0,
                        "#f7a35c"
                    ],
                    [
                        1,
                        "rgba(247,163,92,0)"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "marker": {
                "fillColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "lineWidth": 2
            },
            "lineWidth": 2,
            "states": {
                "hover": {
                    "lineWidth": 1
                }
            },
            "threshold": null
        },
        "line": {
            "lineWidth": 4,
            "threshold": null,
        },
        "spline": {
            "lineWidth": 4,
            "threshold": null
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "area",
            "name": "Heart Rate",
            "data": [
            
            ["2020-08-31T16:01:56-05:00",71],
            ["2020-09-01T09:21:28-04:00",67],
            ["2020-09-02T08:28:47-05:00",{"y":76,"marker":{"enabled":true,"symbol":"triangle","fillColor":"#ff0000","lineColor":"#ff0000"}}],
            ["2020-09-03T09:18:15-05:00",68],
            ["2020-09-03T20:15:35-05:00",70],
            ["2020-09-04T20:14:52-05:00",65],
            ["2020-09-05T09:21:51-05:00",69],[
            "2020-09-05T21:02:11+05:00",62],
            ["2020-09-06T11:08:15-05:00",62],
            ["2020-09-06T20:16:05+08:00",70],
            ["2020-09-07T08:02:10-05:00",72],
            ["2020-09-09T12:22:28-01:00",86],
            ["2020-09-10T08:41:15-05:00",62],
            ["2020-09-10T20:01:22+07:00",71],
            ["2020-09-11T08:02:18-05:00",{"y":62,"marker":{"enabled":true,"symbol":"triangle","fillColor":"#ff0000","lineColor":"#ff0000"}}],
            ["2020-09-13T08:01:43-05:00",76],
            ["2020-09-13T20:01:14+07:00",73],
            ["2020-09-13T20:05:04+07:00",63],
            ["2020-09-15T08:01:57-05:00",{"y":71,"marker":{"enabled":true,"symbol":"triangle","fillColor":"#ff0000","lineColor":"#ff0000"}}]
            ],
            "color": "#f7a35c",
            "marker": {
                "fillColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "lineWidth": 2,
                "lineColor": null
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
["2020-09-02T08:28:47-05:00", {
  "y": 76,
  "marker": {
    ...
  }
}]
```

You should use:

```
{
  name: "2020-09-03T09:18:15-05:00",
  y: 68,
  "marker": {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2xoqfLya/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.area.data

Comment: awsome, thank you very much. I was trying x: '2020-09-03T09:18:15-05:00' instead of name: ''. This is a great help.